# How to convert string to FIXMessage?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to modify the price value from the QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh message (type W).

I had successfully convert the raw FIXMessage to string type. But is there any way I can revert it back to FIXMessage from string after I modify the value?

Here are the code I've done so far:

```
public void alterMarkup(QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh snapshot) 
{
    // convert FIXMessage to string type
    String message = System.Convert.ToString(snapshot);

    // retrieve the value to modify
    String a = message.Substring(message.LastIndexOf("269=0") + 10);
    String bid_value = a.Substring(0, a.IndexOf("\u0001"));

    String b = message.Substring(message.LastIndexOf("269=1") + 10);
    String ask_value = b.Substring(0, b.IndexOf("\u0001"));

    // alter the price
    Decimal deci_bid = System.Convert.ToDecimal(bid_value) + 0.1m;

    // NoMDEntries Group
    QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries group = new QuickFix44.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries();         

    group.setField(new QuickFix.MDEntryType(System.Convert.ToChar(QuickFix.MDEntryType.BID)));
    group.setField(new QuickFix.MDEntryPx(System.Convert.ToDouble(deci_bid)));
    group.setField(new QuickFix.MDEntrySize(0));
    group.setField(new QuickFix.MDEntryDate());
    group.setField(new QuickFix.MDEntryTime(DateTime.UtcNow));
    group.setField(new QuickFix.TradingSessionID());
    group.setField(new QuickFix.TradingSessionSubID());
    group.setField(new QuickFix.QuoteCondition(System.Convert.ToString(QuickFix.QuoteCondition.OPEN_ACTIVE)));
    group.setField(new QuickFix.MDEntryOriginator());
    group.setField(new QuickFix.QuoteEntryID());
    group.setField(new QuickFix.QuoteType(QuickFix.QuoteType.TRADEABLE)); 

    Console.WriteLine(snapshot);

    snapshot.replaceGroup(System.Convert.ToUInt32(deci_bid), group.field(), group);

    // print out from second time to compare
    Console.WriteLine(snapshot);
}
```

I printed out the messages and translate it at https://fixparser.targetcompid.com/.

*This is the original message:*
[image: Original message]

*This is the modified message:*
[image: Modified message]

From the images, we can notice that the value of field has to be inserted one by one. If not, it will only show null there.

***P.S.*** Is there any way to only change the MDEntryPx (for both BID and OFFER) instead of changing whole group.

I am quite new to QuickFIX. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to convert it to string and back?

These are all proper ways to set a field value:

```
snapshot.MDEntryType = new MDEntryType('0');
snapshot.MDEntryType = new MDEntryType(MDEntryType.BID); //enum instead of char
snapshot.Set(new MDEntryType('0')) //can also use enum
```

This is all in [the documentation](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/sending-messages.html).

Comment: I am trying to convert it back and forth because I want to alter the MDEntryPx (for both BID and OFFER) in the NOMDEntries group. The **snapshot** cannot be used as `snapshot.MDEntryType` or `snapshot.Set(new MDEntry Type())` because a variable cannot used like a type (error given). I've updated what I tried using `replaceGroup` on my question. But I need to change/replace the whole group.
P.S. I only wish to change the MDEntryPx, the rest remain unchange. Do I need to replace the whole group instead?